# How to enable column based select-copy in DataTables jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table generated using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html).
Is there a method I can use to enable column only select-copying (mouse-based)?

In this figure, for example, I'd like to copy only the `Name` column, but it only provide whole table selection.

[image]

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector

Comment: no this is not what I want. I want to literally copy paste the column from the browser and not storing the selected column in a variable.

Comment: As a workaround you could use TableTools copy functionality.  Keep the button hidden and activate copy of a certain column programmatically on click on the header (or whatever :).

Comment: Not sure if it is possible, but that link I provided says there is a function option available, which could possibly be added to to include some further coding after the data has been selected! https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector#Function